# Opera 9 float:left inside position:relative cause problems

Tags: css, css-float, position, opera

I got anchor with `float:left;` inside div with `position:relative;margin-bottom:15px;`.
for some reason, the margin-bottom dont apply and when I tested it I figured that the problem is related to the float and the relative position.

I have no idea how to fix it and I'll appreciate your help.

[fiddle with the HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/EC2yw/)

screenshot of how it should look and how it really looks:
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason to care about such an outdated version of Opera, with all the bugs that entails?

Comment: well, I want my website to be supported in the lowest version of each browser that has css2 > chrome, firefox 3, ie6, opera9 and safari (dont know which version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

margins with floated elements are usually more trouble than they're worth.  Use padding instead.

Comment: I got another element inside that div which is absolute position (in the bottom). If I use padding inside margin it will move the absolute position div to wrong place..

Comment: You could either adjust the absolute positioning accordingly to match the padding or otherwise modify the DOM so the floated element is contained within a wrapper that provides the padding.

Comment: the first way is better but yet I want to see if some one gives me a better solution

Comment: It appears that overflow:hidden (in the clear class or the container div) resolves the problem...

Comment: that helps with float issues, a clearfix would probably also do the trick